# editing static *.a library

Tags: gnome-terminal, libraries

I was wondering if it's possible to see the content of one of the libraries on my system.

I went to usr/lib directory with my terminal. and I tried `nano` and `vi` but I couldn't see their content.

Is there a way?

Comment: Consider using a hex editor. Search "Hex editor" on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries are binary files, so you won't be able to see the contents using a text editor or any regular text file reading program like `cat`, `less` etc.

Your best bet would be to use `strings` to read the readable contents from the library.

Comment: `strings` is a good idea. :)

Answer (score 2):

A static library file ending with the `.a` extension is simply an archive of the compiled object files from the source code. You can unpack the object files into a directory, from the `foo.a` file, using the *ar* tool in a terminal.

However, this still does not allow you to edit the source and make changes. If you want to modify the program in question, then you should find the source code for the upstream project which created the file, and then modify and recompile that source.

Also, even if you were able to modify the `foo.a` file using a hex editor or similar and change the functionality, it would be a virtually useless change, as anything which linked to that file would need to be rebuilt with the new version, to adapt the changes.